# Issue : Trying to register my Emulator (Google cloud messaging)?

Tags: android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I have downloaded some Google cloud messaging sample application. If I run my example application. unfortunately, gcm-client-demo has stopped. I got this kind of problem.

1. I have sender id, app key and server url.
2. compulsory I need to sig-in for google account for my emulator. Right now my emulator not
   sign-in

why i am facing this problem please explain me..

logcat:

```
02-28 14:48:03.189: D/AndroidRuntime(976): Shutting down VM
02-28 14:48:03.189: W/dalvikvm(976): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(GCMRegistrar.java:98)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:51)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-28 14:48:03.229: E/AndroidRuntime(976):  ... 11 more
02-28 14:48:03.260: W/ActivityManager(372):   Force finishing activity com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/.DemoActivity
02-28 14:48:03.279: W/WindowManager(372): Failure taking screenshot for (343x201) to layer 21010
02-28 14:48:03.719: I/Choreographer(372): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-28 14:48:03.809: W/ActivityManager(372): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4125ba80 com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/.DemoActivity}
02-28 14:48:04.718: I/Choreographer(930): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-28 14:48:05.369: I/ARMAssembler(36): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00008001_00000000 [113 ipp] (134 ins) at [0x41407610:0x41407828] in 8278218 ns
02-28 14:48:06.488: I/ActivityManager(372): No longer want com.android.contacts (pid 544): hidden #16
02-28 14:48:16.499: W/ActivityManager(372): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4125ba80 com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/.DemoActivity}
02-28 14:52:21.518: D/dalvikvm(456): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 9% free 6557K/7175K, paused 32ms+13ms, total 125ms
02-28 14:53:03.318: I/Process(976): Sending signal. PID: 976 SIG: 9
02-28 14:53:03.378: I/ActivityManager(372): Process com.google.android.gcm.demo.app (pid 976) has died.
02-28 14:53:03.428: W/InputMethodManagerService(372): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41317c60 attribute=null
02-28 14:53:17.979: E/ThrottleService(372): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-28 14:59:57.108: D/dalvikvm(456): GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 9% free 6555K/7175K, paused 17ms+9ms, total 98ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though your emulator does not have the Google API's installed, based on this error message:

```
Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
```

You can read about the GCM client requirements in the Google GCM docs: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#requirements

The important part being this:

> For the Android application:
>
> - Emulator (or device) running Android 2.2 with Google APIs.
> - The Google API project number of the account registered to use GCM.

So when you create your emulator make sure that the target has the Google API's installed. E.g.:

```
Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 10
```